# jquery auto complete for dynamically generated textboxes not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

i can't do autocomplete on dynamically generated textboxes, i have searched internet but couldn't found any solution. i'm sharing what i have done so far:

JQUERY:

```
function bindAutoComplete(classname) {
    $("." + classname).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/Ticket/GetPart',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.PartNumber, value: item.PartNumber };
                            }))
                        }
                        else {
                            response([{ label: 'No results found.' }]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        },
    });

}

// fetch part number
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#PartNumber23").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/Ticket/GetPart',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.PartNumber, value: item.PartNumber };
                            }))
                        }
                        else {
                            response([{ label: 'No results found.' }]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        },
    });

    $('#PartNumber23').keyup(function () {
        var errormsg = "";
        var amount = $('#PartNumber23').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Admin/Ticket/GetPart',
            data: { 'term': amount },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        $('#Manufacturer').val(data[1].Manufacturer);
                        $('#DateCode').val(data[0].DateCode);
                        $('#Package').val(data[0].PackageCase);
                        $('#buyingprice').val(data[0].Price);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#Manufacturer').val('');
                        $('#DateCode').val('');
                        $('#Package').val('');
                        $('#buyingprice').val('');
                    }
                }

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                $('#error').html(jqXHR)
            }
        });
    });
})

var key = function () {
    var errormsg = "";
    var amount = $('#buyingprice').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/Ticket/ConvertCurrency",
        data: "{amount:" + amount + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#bpusd').val(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            // $('#error').html("Primitive Functions not allowed.")
        }
    });
}

var key2 = function () {
    var errormsg = "";
    var amount = $('#customprice').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/Ticket/ConvertCurrency",
        data: "{amount:" + amount + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#amtusd').val(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            // $('#error').html("Primitive Functions not allowed.")
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#PartNumber23').keyup(key);
    $('#buyingprice').keyup(key);
    $('#customprice').keyup(key2);
    $('#Quantity').keyup(function () {
        var qty = $('#Quantity').val();
        $('#CustomQuantity').val(qty);
    })
})

$("#AddMore").click(function () {

    $("#maintable").each(function () {

        var tds = '<tr>';

        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
            tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
        });
        tds += '</tr>';

        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {

            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            $("#delete").fadeIn('200');
        }
        else {
            $(this).append(tds);
        }
    });

    bindAutoComplete('inputs')

});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="maintable">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                Part No
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                MFG
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                DC
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                PKG
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                QTY. Need
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                QTY. Offer
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                BP
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                BP(USD)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                AMT (USD)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                LT Days
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Desc
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Note
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input class="inputs" type="text" name="abcd" id="PartNumber23" style="width:130px;" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input class="text-box single-line" id="Manufacturer" name="Manufacturer" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Manufacturer" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input class="text-box single-line" id="DateCode" name="DateCode" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DateCode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input class="text-box single-line" id="Package" name="Package" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Package" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." data-val-required="The Quantity field is required." id="Quantity" name="Quantity" style="width:35px;" type="number" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Quantity" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input class="text-box single-line" id="CustomQuantity" name="CustomQuantity" style="width:35px;" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CustomQuantity" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input class="text-box single-line" id="buyingprice" name="BuyingPrice" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="BuyingPrice" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input id="bpusd" name="ConvertedBP" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConvertedBP" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input id="amtusd" name="ConvertedAmount" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConvertedAmount" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                                <span id="error" class="error"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input id="LTDays" name="LTDays" type="text" value="" />
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LTDays" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <select class="drop" id="Description" name="Description"><option>Original ROHS</option>
<option>ROHS Compliance</option>
</select>
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Description" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <textarea class="txtarea text-box multi-line" id="Note" name="Note" placeholder="Any Note With Ticket">
</textarea>
                                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Note" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

i have replace the id with class but autocomplete only works on already present textboxes not with dynamic textbox

Comment: your autocomplete code should injected after new texbox is added

Comment: you have to explicitly call autocomplete for the new `<input>`

Comment: @shaunakde how could i do that possibly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this **[Working Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CA2D9/)**.

**JS**

```
bindAutoComplete('inputs');
$("#AddMore").click(function () {

    $("#maintable").each(function () {

        var tds = '<tr>';

        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
            tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
        });
        tds += '</tr>';

        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {

            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            bindAutoComplete('inputs');
            $("#delete").fadeIn('200');
        }
        else {
            $(this).append(tds);
            bindAutoComplete('inputs');
        }
    });
});

function bindAutoComplete(classname){
$("."+classname).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/Ticket/GetPart',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.PartNumber, value: item.PartNumber };
                            }))
                        }
                        else {
                            response([{ label: 'No results found.' }]);
                        }
                    }
               }
          })
      },
 });

}
```

After appending input elements call `bindAutoComplete('inputs')`

---

**HTML** - Add classname, for example: `class="inputs"` to `<input>` tags.

```
<input type="text" class="inputs" name="abcd" class="PartNumber23" style="width:130px;" />
```

Comment: thanks for the code help but i cannot generate id and it is not working, can u please guide me?

Comment: check the updated code. And post your full html in the question, which includes `#maintable1` and every required element

Comment: Updated my answer check the link, the ajax wont work on my side, but copy paste the code at you side.

Comment: Thanks, your code worked but i have other textboxes on which i'm binding the autocomplete response with your code other textboxes stopped working, i have updated all the code please check and please guide me, it would be a great help from your side because i'm stuck here from hours :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54980/discussion-between-usama-sheikh-and-shaunakde).

Comment: i have modify the code u sent now it is working but i'm getting the same value on all dynamic textboxes, can u tell me please how can i solve this new problem?